# PubNub JavaScript SDK: PNmessage is not defined

Tags: javascript, push-notification, pubnub

I'm trying to follow this tutorial for sending Push Messages using PubNub JavaScript SDK - https://www.pubnub.com/docs/swift/mobile-gateway#Publishing_to_APNS

However, when I try to run the page in the browser, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: PNmessage is not defined
```

A quick Google brought this answer - https://www.pubnub.com/community/discussion/501/phonegap-android-gcm-push-notification-error-pnmessage-is-undefined but it didn't really solve my problem even using the latest JavaScript SDK (3.9.2).

I also can't post new questions on the PubNub Developer Community so I am trying my luck here. Anyone with the similar experience and has a workaround to this problem?

Comment: That community post **may be outdated**!  I posted to you an answer below with updated reference docs.

Answer (score 0):

## Android Push Notifications

A step-by-step tutorial for Google Cloud Messaging to Android using PhoneGap.

https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2014-12-18-sending-android-push-notifications-via-gcm-javascript-using-phonegap/

## iOS Push Notifications

A step-by-step tutorial how to send and receive iOS push notifications for devices via APNS.

https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2014-12-22-sending-ios-push-notifications-via-apns-javascript-using-apns-phonegap/

Comment: Sorry, I was actually able to reach support by emailing support@pubnub.com. They gave me a new build of the JS SDK and a new syntax for initializing/getting PNmessage from pubnub object (`message = pubnub.PNmessage()` instead of `message = PNmessage()`). This will be released within the next day.

Comment: When i use message = pubnub.PNmessage() it throws the same error. I am using the appcelerator sdk.